# Is is legal for an ISP to perform planned maintenance that causes an outage without warning?

Tags: internet

Is it legal for an internet service provider (ISP) to stop servicing customers without any warning while the ISP performs maintenance that was planned at least 12 hours in advance?

If not legal, could the damages be tied at all to the customer activity being performed online at the time?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what your contract with your ISP says. Since your ISP drafted it it probably says no you can't.

Comment: The contract covers situations about resolving "outages".  I think the average reader would interpret "outages" as the unplanned acts of god variety.  For the known-in-advance maintenance events, could I claim they are exercising [negligence](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/negligence)?

Comment: I think the law would interpret outage as outage - i.e. An interruption to the service.

Comment: ISPs often have consumer contracts and business contracts. The product delivered is exactly the same. Business contracts pay more. Typically if you are on the consumer contract, you can ask for your payment for 12 hours back, likely something like 50 cents. If you are on the business contract, conditions are very much different.